# App Engine request w/ user cookie failure on production (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cookies, urllib2

Im using app engine to call a service on another domain and return that data to app engine. The service requires a cookie, so I added it to the header request. This works on my local DEV environment but when I deploy to app engine production it does not return the data when the cookie is applied to the header.

```
recent_url = urllib2.build_opener()
recent_url.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'dk_rv_pro_cd=UN75ES9000FXZA'))
recent = json.loads(recent_url.open("http://www.samsung.com/us/function/recentlyViewedYourDevices.do").read())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that urllib2 uses app engine's urlfetch service, which does not handle cookies when passed in that way. This blog post by a user who encountered a similar problem may help: http://everydayscripting.blogspot.nl/2009/08/google-app-engine-cookie-handling-with.html